# How to restrict push code in AWS CodeCommit Repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I have two different repository in AWS CodeCommit for e.g. A & B repository and I have one credential with full permission of CodeCommit so in my case I want user can only push & pull code from A repository but they cannot push code into B repository but they can only able to pull the code from B repository.

Anyone know about this please help me.

thanks in Advance.

I search on google but not get expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an IAM policy that grants permissions to perform any action on any repository, you'll have to add another policy that explicitly denies the actions such as `GitPush` for repository B. The following policy should work for that.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyGitPushForSpecificRepo",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPush"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:111111111111:Repository-B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you'll have to adapt the region, account and repository name of course in the resource string. Also, if you'd like to deny additional actions on the repository (such as `DeleteBranch`), you'll need to add those to the action section.

Comment: thank you so much friend this article is very helpful for me also working fine